# jQuery not working with hash in URL

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, themeroller

Using jQuery Mobile with ThemeRoller theme, the accordion menu delivers a URL with hash when "Cake Sizes" is clicked.  The ThemeRoller theme does not load with has in URL.

```
<div><h3><a href="#">Cakes</a></h3>
<div id="accordion-child">
<div><h3><a href="/cakes/cake-sizes" data-transition="slideup">Cake Sizes</a></h3></div>
<div><h3><a href="/cakes/flavors">Flavors</a></h3></div>
<div><h3><a href="/cakes/gallery">Gallery</a></h3></div>
</div>
</div>
```

When click "Cake Sizes" URL is http://example.com/#/cakes/cake-sizes

How do I prevent # from ending up in URL or how do I remove it?  Does anyone know why Themeroller theme will not load with hash in URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have the `#` in the `href` for cakes anyway. Leave it blank and it will behave in the same manner.

Comment: Good suggestion. I tried that and it does not work.  Somehow the hash is added. The status bar says mydomain.com/cakes/cake-sizes, but when i click and the page loads the URL has the hash in it: mydomain.com/#/cakes/cake-sizes.  I think only my custom css is actually working and none of the other css.

Comment: It seems to work for me... I believe the # is coming from someplace else for you...

Comment: Could you send me your code?  I wonder if it's my jquery script call.

Comment: I was testing with a browser.  The JQM Controls do not load in a browser (it not being a handheld device) and this created the "error".  You have to tell the browser to pretend to be a handheld device.

Answer (score 0):

By default jquery mobile using ajax calls to load pages. So the "#" included automatically in the url. To avoid that,use

> data-ajax="false"

to disable ajax call on the hyperlinks. And try like this

```
<div><h3><a href="#" data-ajax="false">Cakes</a></h3>
```

Hope it works...